# How do you retrieve the latest Document from a MongoCollection (MongoDB v3.3)

Tags: java, mongodb

How do you retrieve the most recently added Document from a MongoCollection using Java? Most of the existing references describe how to do this in v2. How do you do this in v3.3?

I suppose it has something to do with the find(Bson filter) method. How do you specify the Bson filter and how do you convert a FindIterable to a Document?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the $natural sort order. On your MongoDb query specify the sort :

```
{ $natural : -1}
```

Then limit by 1 and you have the correct document